# How to test memory advance pattern?

Tags: command-line, hardware, ram, c++

I am new learner in Ubuntu. I want know about how to execute memory advance pattern test? Is there any ubuntu command or c++ program?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this test? As already answered, memtest is usually performed from the boot menu, is there any particular reason you want to do it specifically from a booted system?

Answer (score 0):

If you are dual boot on startup when grub appears choose the memtest option. If not dual boot while system is booting hit shift and choose the memtest option.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But i need any c++ program or any ubuntu package or that can test it without any boot

Comment: Memory can not be test while running any OS it just does not work that way.